# jquery keydown and mouseDown function?

Tags: jquery, html, audio, keydown, mousedown

I have code, which have many divs and while I mousedown them browser play different sounds and stop when I mouseup.
I need to emulate this MouseDown function by pressing keybuttons on my keyboard.

```
$( function() {
    var idx = 0,
    $letters = $( '.note' );
    $letters.each( function( i ) {
        $( this ).mouseDown( function() {
            var letter = $( this ).text();
            if ( alphabetSounds[ letter ] ) {
                alphabetSounds[ letter ].play();
            }
        });
    });
    $letters.each( function( i ) {
        $( this ).mouseUp( function() {
            var letter = $( this ).text();
            if ( alphabetSounds[ letter ] ) {
                alphabetSounds[ letter ].stop();
            }
        });
    });
});
$("body").on("keydown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $note1 = $(".1c");
    var $note2 = $(".1cc");
    if(e.keyCode == 90) {
        $note1.mouseDown();
    }
```

!!!!Trouble in this part

```
    if(e.keyCode == 88) {
        $note2.mouseDown();
    }
});
```

How can I fix it, need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters)

```
if(e.keyCode == 88) 
{
   $note2.trigger('mousedown');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zPUe4/)

Comment: Thank you! Really easy and usefull for me)